# How to fix 'float object is not callable' error?

Tags: python

I'm working on my first recursive code but before I've gotten to the recursive part I'm getting an error that I don't know how to fix.

It seems to me like the problem is with the "l" variable. I tried making this 1 instead of 1.0 and it turned into an 'int' object is not callable error. I also tried going in and replacing all of the variables in f with numbers and got an 'int' object is not callable error and the same error when I leave c and r in but replace l with 1.

```
#r = radius of wire
r = 0.1011
#t = length of tube
t = 77.4
#n = number of loops
n = t/(2*r)
#c = circumference of tube
c = 28.08
#d = density of wire
d = 0.000896
#l = number of layers
l = 1.0
#f = circumference with wire
f = (((2**(l-1))*c*(r**(l-1)))+((2**(l))(r**(l))))
#v = volume of wire
v = (f-c)*t
#m = mass of wire
m = d*v
print(m)
```

Comment: You're trying to call an `int` object here: `((2**(1))(0.1011**(1))`. You're missing a `*` symbol.

Comment: It would help if you simplified your expression by eliminating the more obviously unnecessary subexpressions, like `0.1011**(1)`, which is just `0.1011`.

Comment: And why define `r = 0.1011` et al. if you aren't going to use them in calculating `f`?

Answer (score -1):

you missed *

```
f = (((2**(1-1))*28.08*(0.1011**(1-1)))+((2**(1))*(0.1011**(1))))
```

Comment: Obviously it is the answer.The problem was a missing * between ((2**(1)) and (0.1011**(1))

Answer (score -1):

You've missed an operation here

```
...((2**(1))(0.1011**(1))))
```

it's calculated as:

```
...2(0.1011**(1)))
```

and '2' is not a function